# zsh/oh-my-zsh: how to make tab completion add no trailing space for non-folder files?

Tags: zsh, autocomplete, whitespace

I installed zsh and oh-my-zsh.

By default, when using tab completion zsh adds a trailing space for non-folder files.

For demonstration I created the following folders/files in a folder named `test_files` and `cd`ed into `test_files`:

```
test_files
├── dir1
│   └── file4
├── dir2
│   └── file5
├── file1
├── file11
└── file111
```

First, I pressed `l, s, Space, Tab, Tab, Tab, *, Enter` in turn and got `ls dir2/*` as the 1st command. Second, I pressed `l, s, Space, Tab, Tab, Tab, Tab, *, Enter` in turn and got `ls file1 *` as the 2nd command. Please see the gif picture below:

[image: zsh ls commands]

For the 2nd command, since "file1" is not a folder, a space was added between "file1" and "*".

I don't want the space added between "file1" and "*", because when I mean to delete files staring with "file1" in their names I'll possibly press `r, m, Space, -, r, f, Space, Tab, Tab, Tab, Tab, *, Enter` in turn, and I think the command will be `rm -rf file1*`, but the command will actually be `rm -rf file1 *` and sometimes I may press 'y' without noticing the added space, so I may delete all the folders and files by mistake. Please see the gif picture below:

[image: zsh rm command]

I used to delete many folders and files by mistake.

I googled many days for removing that space but have not succeed.

I found add-space from zsh document pretty looks what I want, then I tried `zstyle ':completion:*' add-space false`, but it seems that nonthing changed.

I tried only place the following lines in my `.zshrc`, it still adds that space:

```
autoload -U compinit && compinit
zmodload -i zsh/complist
zstyle ':completion:*' menu select
zstyle ':completion:*' add-space false
```

If I remove `zstyle ':completion:*' menu select`, the space is not added, but the cursor won't traverse the folders/files when pressing the tab key, so I want to keep `menu select` in configs. Please see the gif picture below:

[image: zsh rm command without menu select]

I also tried many other configs.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `*` to [`$ZLE_REMOVE_SUFFIX_CHARS`](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#index-ZLE_005fREMOVE_005fSUFFIX_005fCHARS).

```
ZLE_REMOVE_SUFFIX_CHARS=$' \t\n;&|*'
```

(here appended to the value used by default when the variable is not set)

So the suffix that completion inserts, whether it's `/` or *space* be removed when typing `*` after the selected completion.